# Using Spinner of Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces-3.0.M3 with Tomcat 7.
Spinner always shows blank rather than the value assigned to it.
It shows NaN if up/down button is clicked.

Code is given below:

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="Default Value" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputLabel value=""/>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="input">
             <p:spinner id="rangeSpinner" value="#{bean.hm_Range[minIndex]}" min="#{bean.hm_Range[minIndex]}" max="#{bean.hm_Range[maxIndex]}" rendered="#{bean.FIELDTYPE == 2}"/>
        </f:facet>   
    </p:cellEditor> 
</p:column>
```

Is it bug with Spinner ?

Comment: Please post some Java code. If hm_Range is a list, you can't save the value in that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using inputBox with RangeValidation as the problem was not resolved with primefaces-3.1.RC1 also

Answer (score 1):

Update to RC2, M3 is quite old. I remember fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return an int to the spinner , If you use Integer , make sure its not a NULL

The value of the spinenr should be an int or not NULL integer (not sure how the list will work for you , if at all)

here a bunch of spinner examples [Spinner](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/spinner.jsf)